# Sorting a table in Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to sort a table using the following VBA code. The code does select the correct column, and the column filter does get a small arrow in it, indicating that it is sorted. But the rows do not sort. They stay unsorted.

What is wrong?

```
Sub SortTableTest()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim columnToSortBy As Range

    Set tbl = Sheets("PB").ListObjects("AI")
    Set columnToSortBy = tbl.ListColumns(9).Range

    'Sort table
    With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add columnToSortBy, xlDescending
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Additionally, if you know how I can reference the column I am interested in by name instead of by column, that would be great.

Comment: Since `table` is often a misnomer in Excel a lot of people are likely looking for how to sort data in general: [Sort data based on column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802574/sort-data-based-on-one-column-affecting-the-entire-table-vba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you missed one parameter in `.SortFields.Add method`. What you need is:

```
.SortFields.Add columnToSortBy, xlSortOnValues, xlDescending
```

Second, question from you comment. Try with this kind of References:

```
Set columnToSortBy = Range(tbl.Name & "[[#All],[column name here]]")
```

Comment: When I use Range as mentioned above, I get the error method 'Range' of object _Global failed? I know, this is Avery old thread...may be somebody could help me?

Comment: @Venu, you should somehow show your code. Best idea is to post your own question.