# Sort Data based on one column affecting the entire table VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a table where I am sorting based on the data entries in Column E. However, when I am using my code, (below) my rows for which the column become disorganized and mismatched. Each row needs to contain the same data entries as before they were sorted, only moving to be sorted based on the values in column E. I am trying to sort this table, with my expected outcome shown below:

Code:

```
    With Worksheets("Fruits")
    Dim FruitsLastRow As Long
    Dim FruitsKeyRange As Range
        
        FruitsLastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set DashboardRange = Range("E17:G" & FruitsLastRow)

        
        DashboardRange.Sort key1:=Range("E17:E" & FruitsLastRow), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo _           

    End With
```

This is what I have
[image]

This is what I need
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify just the top cell instead of all cells for *key1* parameter ([Range.Sort example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort)).

```
DashboardRange.Sort key1:=Range("E17"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the top cell specifically, you can specify any one cell in the column used for sorting. `DashboardRange.Sort key1:=Range("E19"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo` works here too